# MS Access like query with # in the result

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, sql-like, where-clause

I'm just trying to have a query that searches for "#" in a field.

```
SELECT dbo_PartNumber.*
FROM dbo_PartNumber WHERE (dbo_PartNumber.[Part Number] like  "*#*");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose `#` in square brackets:

```
like  "*[#]*"
```

Find more here [Like Operator](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931)

Comment: I didnt realize you put the  brackets only around the #